# What is the alternative of csshX for Kubernetes Pods?

Tags: kubernetes, ssh, kubectl

I use `kubectl exec -it` for logging into a single Kubernetes pod.

Is there any way to log in to multiple pods in a cluster, at the same time with a single command (just like `csshX`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a plugin that could help you with this. It's called [kubectl-tmux-exec](https://github.com/predatorray/kubectl-tmux-exec):

> A kubectl plugin that controls multiple pods simultaneously using
> [Tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux).
>
> It is to `kubectl exec` as `csshX` or `pssh` is to `ssh`.
>
> Instead of exec bash into multiple pod's containers one-at-a-time,
> like `kubectl exec pod{N} /bin/bash`.
>
> You can now use
>
> ```
> kubectl tmux-exec -l app=nginx /bin/bash
> ```

All necessary details regarding [Installation](https://github.com/predatorray/kubectl-tmux-exec#installation) and [Usage](https://github.com/predatorray/kubectl-tmux-exec#usage) can be found in the linked docs.

Answer (score 0):

I use csshx itself:

```
csshx localhost+n
```

n being the amount of pods in a cluster, then from within each slave I do:

```
kubectl exec -it $pod -- bash
```

The most interesting part is figuring out how to put a different pod in $pod ( I use a bash function which will write a local file to check if a pod name was already used and read the following one although you may probably figure out a way to use the slave id as an index for the pod list to make it simpler)